# No perder la información al refrescar la pagina

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando el usuario presione <kbd>F5</kbd> y refresque la página no se pierdan los datos?.

De momento he hecho un `session_start()` pero no sé qué hacer ahora.

He estado investigando pero todo lo que me he encontrado son para formularios, la página que yo tengo no es un formulario.

Comment: Si no es un formulario ¿qué datos hay?

Comment: Si no te refieres a un formulario que está a medio rellenar, ¿podrías explicar un poco mejor qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Necesitas algo para guardar la información entre una carga y otra, aquí entran las sesiones, y adicionalmente bases de datos y archivos. Peroooo, si no tienes un formulario, no recibes datos, si no recibes datos, no los puedes guardar... porque, aunque uses session, ¿qué vas a guardar, si no recibes nada? ¿la hora? Explica mejor lo que quieres hacer, para que podamos al menos orientarte. Porque, si tienes, no sé, una página en la que se puede escribir, y, sin preparar nada, no quieres que se pierda lo escrito tras recargar la página... entonces vas mal.

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Seria interesante que intentes ver la posibilidad de usar cookie(). Eso dependerá de que es lo que realmente necesitas hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar las variables $_SESSION tendras mas información 
http://php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

(PHP) Puedes utilizar una sesión. Por ejemplo, yo quiero conservar el valor de una variable, en pantalla, aunque refresque la página. Tu código debería quedar de esta forma.

```
session_start(); //es la primera linea que debes escribir ANTES DE CUALQUIER OTRA
$nombre = 'Marc'; //inicializas la variable
$_SESSION['nombre'] = $nombre; //le asignas el valor a la sesión
echo $_SESSION['nombre']; // muestra el valor que contiene la sesión;
```

[Documentacion y ejemplos AQUÍ](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Pero cómo puedo usar una variable de sesión en html ? Es decir, tengo un array con varias imágenes, he creado una variable de sesión que guarde ese array, pero cuando voy a hacer un echo de la posición 0 del array de sesión, me salta un error.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, es necesario que compartas el código; de esa forma es mucho más fácil corregir y tener mayor claridad sobre lo que quieres solucionar.